# ASP.NET: If Page1.aspx opens Page2.aspx in a window, how can I have Page1.aspx refresh once Page2.aspx is closed?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, refresh, edit

If Page1.aspx opens Page2.aspx in a window, how can I have Page1.aspx refresh once Page2.aspx is closed?

I have a page with data on it and I have a LinkButton set up so the user can edit that data. The LinkButton launches another windowed page with some text fields and a "Save" & "Cancel" button.  Once one of those clicks I execute a save and close the window OR just disregard the information and close the window.  I was hoping to have the initial window with the data on it refresh once the 2nd window is closed.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have javascript on the child window (page 2) fire when you are closing out said window
e.g.

```
window.opener.location.reload()
```

Comment: This is only reloading the windowed page that is opened.  Maybe this is because I'm also using `window.close();` ? Also I'm sure it's not helping that I'm being forced! to use iframes... So the page I'm wanting to reload is in an iframe. Perhaps I'm going to have to approach this in another way to work with the iframes.

Comment: @daveomcd the way i did this with a previous project is in the code behind I called this when I was finished with the child window
`string javaScript =
                            "<script type='text/javascript'>\n" +
                            "<!--\n" +
                            "opener.location.reload();\n" +
                            "self.close();\n" +
                            "// -->\n" +
                            "</script>\n";`

I am not too familiar with iframe use but you may want to edit your question to include that information